# PHP - the fastest way to find multiple keywords in text?

Tags: php, html, arrays, regex, parsing

I have a large array of keywords (more than one thousand) and i need to search through a large HTML file to find which keywords are present inside the text. Then i need to return the indexes of these keywords which were found.

For example, if my array is:

```
$keywords = array("love", "money", "minute", "loop"); // etc.
```

and if there are any instances of words "money" and "loop" i want to get an array of:

```
$results = array("1", "3"); // first $keyword element is 0
```

I tried using preg_match_all, but i'm not sure how to get $matches return the indexes of my keywords.

Here's the code i have so far:

```
$keywords = array("love", "money", "minute", "loop");

$html = file_get_contents($url);

preg_match_all("#(love|money|minute|loop)#i", $html, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

This is how the result looks like:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "minute"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "minute"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "money"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "Money"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "minute"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "minute"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "money"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "Money"
  }
}
```

1. What's the fastest / most optimal way of doing that in PHP? Is preg_match_all fine? I want to avoid having to use foreach, that would cause my function to crawl the entire HTML more than a thousand times (not very time effective).
2. How to get indexes of my keywords? E.g. keywords that were found were number 0 and number 3, regardless of their count.

Comment: Indexes? As in the count of words? `love peace and coding` and if keyword is `peace` you want 1 as return?

Comment: Also is `code` part of the string above or not?

Comment: No, match all is definitely not optimal if you only care about whether or not a substring exists, not about where it exists or how many times it exists.  Regex comparisons are also slower than string comparisons.

Comment: `preg_match_all` was not designed to tell you the index of a match on a separate array. Write some code to take the match and find it in your array to get your index. Its one loop...

Comment: @Andreas By indexes i mean which keywords occur in text, so is it keyword number 1 or keyword number 2 or keyword number 75.

Comment: @Devon Oh, ok. What other approach would you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to see which of the keywords was present in the text, you can map `stripos` over the array of keywords.

```
$result = array_map(function ($keyword) use (&$html) {
    return stripos($html, $keyword) !== false;
}, $keywords);
```

Now, `stripos` is just going to find one string in another. It has no concept of words, and if you don't want to match the keywords if they exist as part of a longer word you'll need to use a regular expression with word boundaries. But the expression you're currently using doesn't do that, so it may not be an issue.

Comment: Isn't this going to search the entire content for each keyword one at a time.  So if you have 1000 keywords it will potentially scan the entire string 1000 times.  Although it will stop scanning once it finds each word - if the keyword isn't present it will search to the end of the string.

Comment: While simple, I would expect this solution to perform worse than those in the other answers because it will scan though a large document more than a thousand times

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag to get the offsets:

```
$matches=[];
$html = "love and money make the world loop around in a loop three times per minute";
preg_match_all("#love|money|minute|loop#i", $html, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
foreach ($matches[0] as $m) echo $m[0]." found at index ".$m[1]."\n";

// output:
love found at index 0
money found at index 9
loop found at index 30
loop found at index 47
minute found at index 68
```

Now, this performs *fast enough* for you is for you to evaluate. If it does, there's no point in looking for more complicated alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

```
$keywords = array("love", "money", "minute", "loop");

// The function "GetHtmlWords" gets the html content and clean it from spacial 
// characters
$htmlWordsArray = explode(' ', GetHtmlWords($url));

// Calculate the intersection - intersect return values while preserving keys
// use array_keys to get just the keys. double check if first index is 0 or 1
$result = array_keys(array_intersect($keywords, $htmlWordsArray));

var_dump($result);

// Get the content of the html, cleaned from spacial characters, with space 
// between words
function GetHtmlWords($url) {
  $htmlContent = file_get_contents($url);

  // Handle , and . that may split between words, without space.
  // for example hi.there first,second
  $html = $str_replace([".",","], " ", $htmlContent);

  // Clean the text from spacial characters (including , and .)
  $cleanHtml = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\- ]/', '', $html)

  // Remove duplicate spaces
  $htmlWordsOnly = $str_replace("  ", " ", $html);

  return($htmlWordsOnly);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an alternative using [`str_word_count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) which you don't see much, using 2 as the second parameter splits the string into words in an array with the start position as the key.  Then use `array_intersect()` to match this up with the keywords...

```
$keywords = array("love", "money", "minute", "loop");
// string courtesy of Joni's answer
$html = "love and money make the world loop around in a loop three times per minute";
$words = str_word_count($html, 2);
$match = array_intersect($words, $keywords);
print_r($match);
```

gives...

```
Array
(
    [0] => love
    [9] => money
    [30] => loop
    [47] => loop
    [68] => minute
)
```

Not sure how this performs against any regex, just have to try them.

Or for the short of screen space...

```
print_r(array_intersect(str_word_count($html, 2), $keywords));
```

If you just want if the keyword is present just reverse the order of the arrays in `array_intersect()` (and case insensitive - first convert to lower case using `strtolower()`)...

```
$match = array_intersect($keywords, str_word_count(strtolower($html), 1));
```

which gives...

```
Array
(
    [0] => love
    [1] => money
    [2] => minute
    [3] => loop
)
```

Last update:

Looking at performance, my solution can be optimised by flipping the arrays so that rather than scanning each array for a string value, checking if the key exists will be a lot quicker...

```
$match = array_flip(array_intersect_key(array_flip($keywords), array_flip(str_word_count(strtolower($html), 1))));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function textHasKeywords($parr_listOfKeywords = null, $pstr_text = '') {
    $matches=[];
    return preg_match_all("#".implode("|", $parr_listOfKeywords)."#i", $pstr_text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
}
```

How to use it:

```
$larr_listOfKeywords = array("keyword1", "keyword4");
$lstr_text = 'keyword1 keyword2 keyword3, keyword5';

if ( textHasKeywords($larr_listOfKeywords, $lstr_text) != false ) {
    echo textHaveKeywords($larr_listOfKeywords, $lstr_text);
}
```

This function will return the number of keywords founded or false if no keywords is used in the text. In this example will print 1, because only keyword1 was founded.